# Cocoa - `stringWithContentsOfURL/dataWithContentsOfURL` causes ERROR?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, file

The following code for some reason poradically works. I have checked the URL so many times it's not funny (It returns plain text that I would like to parse). The code was 100% functional then it just stopped working and started giving me a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

There is nothing in the debugging output to post other than a line saying the output is switching to the process twice. (Except sometimes something about a double release.)

So far (as much as I can remember) I have tried:

- Reinstalling the app - it only has problems on the 'Default' run (not the first Run/initiate Run.)
- Running the URL in the browser (chrome, firefox, IE...)
- Putting the call in a `@try / @catch` block
- Using `retain`
- Using a temp `NSAutoreleasePool`
- Splitting up / separating the elements of the call (along with loggin **Everything** - *once it hits the error, nothing gets logged*)
- Using the `dataWithContentsOfURL` functions with the above

---

```
NSAutoreleasePool *tmpPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSString *url_string = [self getNormalVersionDownloadURL];
NSLog(@"urlString: -%@-", url_string);
NSError *er;

NSURL *the_URL = [[NSURL URLWithString:url_string] retain];
NSString *version_String =  [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:the_URL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&er];

NSLog(@"verions_string: -%@-", version_String);

if ([version_String length] < 16)
    return;

[tmpPool release];
```

(`NSAutoreleasePool` and `autorelease` added due to http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1667544)

(Cashed page - [http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8D7zlQdG9PMJ:discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa%3FthreadID%3D1667544+http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa%3FthreadID%3D1667544&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8D7zlQdG9PMJ%3adiscussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1667544%20http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1667544&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com))

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... the autorelease/pool was me trying to help it not crash - it helped it run correctly twice (that's why I included it in the post)

Comment: While we wait, note that `[tmpPool retain]` should be `[tmpPool release]`.

Comment: good catch - but it never gets there

Comment: I’ve read the cached discussion. I’m not able to reproduce your problem and I’m not aware of bugs with synchronous URL downloading, but I do agree that asynchronous URL downloading is the recommended approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

discussions.apple.com is currently down so I cannot read the discussion thread. At any rate:

---

```
NSString *url_string = [[self getNormalVersionDownloadURL] autorelease];
```

Does `-getNormalVersionDownloadURL` return an owned or a non-owned object? You only send `-autorelease` if the method returns an owned object.

---

```
NSError **er;
```

This should be `NSError *er` instead, or it should be initialised with the address of a variable of type `NSError *`. Since the latter is uncommon and unnecessary, the following assumes `NSError *er`.

---

```
NSURL *the_URL = [[NSURL URLWithString:url_string] autorelease];
```

`+URLWithString:` returns an `NSURL` object that you don’t own, hence you don’t (auto)release it.

---

```
version_String = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:the_URL 
    encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:er] autorelease]; //ERROR occurs here
```

Two problems:: `+stringWithContentsOfURL:` returns an `NSString` object that you don’t own, hence you don’t (auto)release it. Furthermore, the third parameter should be `&er` instead of `er`.

Comment: Autorelease - this was what I was trying at the time of posting it (trying things - I changed the **er -> *er and &er `edit`)

Comment: @Wallter I’ll ping back when the site is back online.

Answer (score 0):

URLWithString and stringWithContentsOfURL are convenience methods and then already put the variable in autorelease I don't think you need to add autorelease while creating the_URL and version_String

try to remove autorelease ...